# Elasticsearch Update by Query Script Params max size

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using Elasticsearch 5 with Nest 5 on C#.

I have an entity that looks like this:

```
public class ESMessageRecipients
{
    public int MessageId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerSiteId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public List<string> ContactGuids { get; set; } ....
```

And a mapping like this:

```
client.CreateIndex(indexName, c => c
            .Index(indexName)
            .Settings(s => s
               // Custom analizers
                .Analysis(a => a
                    .Analyzers(an => an
                        .Custom("default", cas => cas.Tokenizer("keyword").Filters(new string[] { "lowercase", "trim" }))
                    )
                )
            )
            .Mappings(m => m
                .Map<ESMessageRecipients>(map => map.AutoMap())
            )
        );
```

I need to update the 'ContactGuids' collection with thousands of guids at the time. I tried to do this with an update by query statement like this:

```
...
.Script(s => s
                .Inline(@"                    
                    if (ctx._source.contactGuids == null) { 
                        ctx._source.contactGuids = new ArrayList(); 
                    }

                    for (int i=0; i < params.guids.length; i++) {
                        if (!ctx._source.contactGuids.contains(params.guids[i])) {
                            ctx._source.contactGuids.add(params.guids[i]);
                        }
                    }                                    
                ")
                .Lang("painless")
                .Params(p => p
                    .Add("guids", newGuids.ToArray())
                )
            )
...
```

But the problem that I have is if I send a big list of guids (like 5k guids) Elastic is throwing an exception. I also tried to sent smaller list (like 1k guids) and it worked on that case.

Here is the exception that I get with 5k guids:

```
Content: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"script_exception","reason":"runtime error","script_stack":["for (int ","^---- HERE"],"script":"
```

Has the script params a size limit?
If that is the case, is there a way to increase the size of the script params that I can send to ES?

This list can have millions of guids, so I need a way to make all this perform very well.

Comment: Have you tried to create a `HashSet` instead and simply add `params.guids` to that set instead of iterating over the whole list?

Comment: For what I can tell, I cannot even do a params.guids.length when passing 5k guids, if I do it ES blow up for some reason.

Comment: If you try with a set, you don't need the for loop at all